# Linux Teaming TLB - same MAC address on both interfaces

Tags: linux, network-teaming

I have following teaming configuration:

```
DEVICE="team0"
DEVICETYPE="Team"
ONBOOT="yes"
BOOTPROTO=none
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
TEAM_CONFIG='"runner": {"name": "loadbalance","tx_hash": ["eth", "ipv4", ipv6"],"tx_balancer": {"name": "basic"}},"ports": {"em1": {}, "em2": {}}'
```

But individual interfaces appear to have same MAC address, which makes this configuration useless, since network switch won't allow two identical MAC addresses on different ports within the same L2 domain (it will cause MAC flap or some vendors even can shutdown such ports):

```
 em1: 
    link/ether 68:05:ca:02:ba:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
 em2: 
    link/ether 68:05:ca:02:ba:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

However, individual ifcfg* files have differeint HWADDRS specified, anyway teaming ignores this. In active-backup configuration it would not introduce any problems since only one NIC will be transmitting.

When I configured the same with old bonding driver (mode 5 or 6), MAC addresses of individual interfaces were different and everything worked as expected. Moreover MS Windows implementation of teaming also uses different MAC addresses per interface.

What is wrong with teaming or I am missing something?

Comment: I believe this explains your question: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2104811

Comment: Explains a bit but not completely - "hwaddr_policy" option works only for activebackup runner, but not for loadbalance.